# python create sublists based on separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sublist

I have a list

```
sentence = ['1', '00', 'and', '4', 'and', '2', '00', 'and', '3']
```

And I'm trying to find a way to create a list of sublists based on the separator "and". So each sublist can have only one "and" in it. And the extra and's just remain as elements of the list without being put in a sublit.

```
sentence = [['1', '00', 'and', '4'], 'and', ['2', '00', 'and', '3']]
```

I tried

```
sentence = ['1', '00', 'and', '4', 'and', '2', '00', 'and', '3']
nbAnd = 0
temp=[]
for i,j in enumerate(sentence):
    t= []
    if j.isdigit():
        t.append(j)
    if j == "and":
        nbAnd +=1
        if nbAnd<1:
            t.append(j)
        else:
            temp.append(j)
            nbAnd=0
    temp.append(t)
print(temp)
```

And this is what I get :

```
[['1'], ['00'], 'and', [], ['4'], 'and', [], ['2'], ['00'], 'and', [], ['3']]
```

ETA:

the digit before "and" must always have a greater 'len' that digit after "and".
So

```
['1', '00', 'and', '4', 'and', '2', '00', 'and', '3', 'and', 'five', 'and', 'six']
```

sould be :

```
[['1', '00', 'and', '4'], 'and', ['2', '00', 'and', '3'], 'and', 'five', 'and', 'six']
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: It's not clear why the expected output is what you want, or how you imagine the code you posted should deliver that result. What are the rules for how to group things?

Comment: In order for us to be able to help you, we need to understand how to arrive from the input you have to the output you want. A single example is not sufficient; if you can't explain what the rules are, perhaps you can add more examples which show different corner cases of the behavior you want? Sorry if this comes across as aggressive; I'm just trying to help clarify what the requirements are.

Comment: A common solution would be to have strictly left- or right-oriented trees, so `[a and [b and [c and d]]]` or `[[[a and b] and c] and d]` but this seems to be neither. Nor does "pair every other" seem to apply (which would produce `[[a and b] and [c and d]]` because the last example has three terms with no grouping `[ ... and five and six]`. Quite frankly, this does not look well-defined at the moment.

Comment: Ok sorry for my angry reply, people get so unfriendly in here sometimes it's really discouraging. What must be in the sublist will allow me to recreate numbers by concat. Basically ['1', '00', 'and', '4'] becomes 104. That's why I need to make a difference between "and" when it's inside what could be a number and any other "and" that's just a coordinator. I don't know if that makes sense. I tried to come up with an example that would show every possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the `sentence` list and keep a `temp` variable to check how many `and` are there. If there are more than 1 `and` just add whatever there in `temp` variable.

```py
output = []
temp = []

for i in sentence:
    if i=='and':
        if 'and' in temp:
            output.append(temp.copy())
            output.append(i)
            temp.clear()
        else:
            temp.append(i)
    else:
        temp.append(i)
        
output.append(temp.copy())
            
print(output)
```

```
[['1', '00', 'and', '4'], 'and', ['2', '00', 'and', '3']]
```

Comment: From the PO's comment to the question, it seems the required logic may more complicated: "What must be in the sublist will allow me to recreate numbers by concat. Basically ['1', '00', 'and', '4'] becomes 104"; his counter-example is that "five and six" should not be grouped.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback, I'll look when back to home